# How to use 2 ComboBox Value as Criteria in my PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, combobox

Good day to everyone.
First of all sorry for the past questions.

How can I use two Comboboxes their value as MySQL criteria?

Here is my code so far

During form load all data from database will show in table

```
<div class= "yesPrint">
    <?php
    $con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
    mysql_select_db("poi",$con);
    $sql = "select name,user_date,user_time,address from tblmarker";
    $mydata = mysql_query($sql,$con);
    ?>

    <font size="2" color="black">
        <div class="dataTables_wrapper form-inline" role="grid">
            <table border=1 class="table table-bordered table-hover dataTable" id='tbody' width="100%" height="100%">
                <tr>
                    <th style="text-align:center;background:#eaeaea;">Crime Name</th>
                    <th style="text-align:center;background:#eaeaea;">Date</th>
                    <th style="text-align:center;background:#eaeaea;">Time</th>
                    <th style="text-align:center;background:#eaeaea;">Address</th>
                </tr>
                <?php
                while ($record = mysql_fetch_array($mydata)){
                    echo "<tr>";
                    echo "<td style='padding-left:10px;'>" . $record['name'] . "</td>";
                    echo "<td style='padding-left:10px;'>" . $record['user_date'] . "</td>";
                    echo "<td style='padding-left:10px;'>" . $record['user_time'] . "</td>";
                    echo "<td style='padding-left:10px;'>" . $record['address'] . "</td>";
                    echo "</tr>";
                }
                ?>
            </table>
        </div>
    </font>
    <?php mysql_close($con); ?>         
</div>
```

Here is the Example of data in Database

```
Crime Name            Date                  Time                 Address
Fire                January 1 2015         11:11                   1
Physical Injuries   March 1 2015           11:11                   3
Robbery             April 1 2015           11:11                  111
Carnapping          May 1 2015             11:11                   qq
```

How can i select Fire by Date of January and 2015

Here is my combobox

```
<select id="onmonth">
    <option>January</option>
    <option>February</option>
    <option>March</option>
    <option>April</option>
    <option>May</option>
    <option>June</option>
    <option>July</option>
    <option>August</option>
    <option>September</option>
    <option>October</option>
    <option>November</option>
    <option>December</option>
</select>
<select id="onyear">
    <option>2014</option>
    <option>2015</option>
    <option>2016</option>
    <option>2017</option>
    <option>2018</option>
    <option>2019</option>
    <option>2020</option>
    <option>2021</option>
    <option>2022</option>
    <option>2023</option>
    <option>2024</option>
    <option>2025</option>
    <option>2026</option>
    <option>2027</option>
    <option>2028</option>
    <option>2029</option>
    <option>2030</option>
</select>
```

Any help or ideas? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the data from the selects as $_REQUEST["onmonth"] and $_REQUEST["onyear"]. You can change $_REQUEST for $_POST or $_GET, depends on your form, although $_REQUEST works for both.

Regarding the query, you can get the info using something like this:

select * from tbl where `date` like '".$_REQUEST["onmonth"]."%' and `date` like '%".$_REQUEST["onyear"]."'

Assuming $_REQUEST["onyear"] = '2015' and $_REQUEST["onmonth"]='January', the query will look like this:

select * from tbl where `date` like 'January%' and `date` like '%2015'

Which means:

`date` like 'January%' = All dates beginning with January
`date` like '%2015' = All dates ending with 2015

I didn't test it, but something along this way should work.

```
<div class= "yesPrint">
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db("poi",$con);
//Query using the FORM SELECT info
$sql = "select * from tbl where `date` like '".$_REQUEST["onmonth"]."%' and `date` like '%".$_REQUEST["onyear"]."'";
$mydata = mysql_query($sql,$con);
?>

<font size="2" color="black">
    <div class="dataTables_wrapper form-inline" role="grid">
        <table border=1 class="table table-bordered table-hover dataTable" id='tbody' width="100%" height="100%">
            <tr>
                <th style="text-align:center;background:#eaeaea;">Crime Name</th>
                <th style="text-align:center;background:#eaeaea;">Date</th>
                <th style="text-align:center;background:#eaeaea;">Time</th>
                <th style="text-align:center;background:#eaeaea;">Address</th>
            </tr>
            <?php
            while ($record = mysql_fetch_array($mydata)){
                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td style='padding-left:10px;'>" . $record['name'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td style='padding-left:10px;'>" . $record['user_date'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td style='padding-left:10px;'>" . $record['user_time'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td style='padding-left:10px;'>" . $record['address'] . "</td>";
                echo "</tr>";
            }
            ?>
        </table>
    </div>
</font>
<?php mysql_close($con); ?>
```

Comment: Can you edit your code using my code above inside the div tag?

Comment: There, added it. But as @fabienm said, I am not taking in consideration possible security issues here. This is just a simple example.

Comment: still gives me an error of Notice: Undefined index: onmonth in C:\wamp\www\New System CS\district5\submit.php on line 6

Comment: base in my research putting isset will fix it how can i insert it? l

Comment: Well, you need to set the name of your select. You have set only the id of the element:

<select id="onmonth" name="onmonth"></select>

<select id="onyear" name="onyear"></select>




In the attribute "name" of a form element is where you set the name of the variable that will receive the information when the form is sent.

Answer (score 0):

(Sorry for saying this in an answer and not in comment but i do not have enough reputation to do so)

I believe that any `<option>` needs a value like this :

```
<option value="2015">2015</option>
<option value="2014">2014</option>
....
```

Where the `value` is the one who will be in `$_REQUEST['onyear']`. The text between the two HTML tags will be the one shown in the `<select>` for the user. You can then do your SQL Query with these two parameters like @Kenzou mentionned. 

**But instead of concatenate your SQL query**, i highly recommend you to use PDO or MySqli to acces your database and use SQL parameters to avoid SQL Injections (Here some info about it :http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp)

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I will consider it